# Can't Link EMR github repository to Notebook

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, amazon-emr

I'm having trouble linking an github repository to a notebook on aws emr. The linking keeps on failing. Couple of notes to see if i'm doing things right:

- Should the repository url on emr contain ".git" at the end? e.g.
  Git repository URL: https://github.com/soyjunto/mono.git or https://github.com/soyjunto/mono
- i followed the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-notebooks-security-groups.html that are also outlined in [Configuring EMR notebook with github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62221521/configuring-emr-notebook-with-github).
  So, I added Secret Manager permission to the notebook role and the HTTPS TCP 443 0.0.0.0/0 outbound rule to the SG for emr notebook.